# Manipulating object arrays for unique data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm working on a project where I've got 2 object arrays and the following are the various cases the data can be in.

```
// Case 1
var arr1=[{id:1,quantity:10}]
var arr2=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:2,quantity:20}]

// Case 2
var arr1=[]
var arr2=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:2,quantity:20}]

// Case 3
var arr1=[{id:1,quantity:12}]
var arr2=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:2,quantity:20}]

// Case 4
var arr1=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:1,quantity:20}]
var arr2=[{id:1,quantity:10}]
```

So, the array1 might be empty, might have one of the objects from array2 or both the objects of array2 with a different quantity value.

I'd like to update the main array or arr1 based on arr2 but don't want to completely swipe arr1 with arr2 with arr1=arr2 kind of solution. arr1 should update quantity based on arr2 and add or remove based on the same thing.

Comment: Can you give a before/after example?

Comment: How can the code both update and add and remove elements at the same time?

Comment: Can you explain how the result would be different from `arr1 = arr2`?

Comment: @trincot because I don't want the api that the data comes from to replace everything stored in the array, causing the views that use the array to go to an empty state and then fill up again, it'd be better if I had a solution as stated above

Comment: I am not sure I understand: if the replacing of the array content happens synchronously, there would be *no moment* at which a view would see the array being empty. I do understand however that *assigning* a new array to the variable will not affect already existing references to the previous array. To deal with that you need to *mutate* the array (as proposed in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `arr1 = arr2` would be a solution, except that you want to *mutate* `arr1` instead of *replacing* it, then consider using `splice`:

```js
var arr1=[{id:0,quantity:1},{id:2,quantity:12},{id:3,quantity:9}],
    arr2=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:2,quantity:20}];

arr1.splice(0, arr1.length, ...arr2);

console.log(arr1);
```

If your concern is that the objects in `arr1` should not be *replaced* when their `id` exists in `arr2`, but be *mutated* (keeping their references), then I would suggest:

```js
var arr1=[{id:0,quantity:1},{id:2,quantity:12},{id:3,quantity:9}],
    arr2=[{id:1,quantity:10},{id:2,quantity:20}];
// key both arrays by id in Maps
var mp1 = new Map(arr1.map(obj => [obj.id, obj])),
    mp2 = new Map(arr2.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]));
// traverse arr1 from right to left so deletions will not affect the loop
arr1.reduceRight( (_, obj, i) => {
    if (mp2.has(obj.id)) {
        Object.assign(obj, mp2.get(obj.id)); // update
    } else {
        arr1.splice(i, 1); // delete
    }
}, null);
arr2.forEach( (obj) => {
    if (!mp1.has(obj.id)) {
        arr1.push(obj); // insert
        // If you need the inserted object to be a copy, then do:
        // arr1.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
    }
});

// If you need the result to be sorted by `id`, then do this also:
arr1.sort( (a,b) => a.id - b.id );

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: I tried this approach but since this adds everything from array2 to array1 and since I'm using this logic in angular for angular-animate and this animates all the additions instead of just one addition. I only want one addition to have the animation effect and not everything, hence asked this question here, else a simple google search would've solved it. Thanks though

Comment: I added a 2nd solution which keeps object references in `arr1` in tact when their `id` exists in `arr2`.

Comment: This looks correct and might work, will test it once I'm home.

Comment: this works but if arr1 has 2 objects and arr2 has only 1, then arr1 still results in 2 objects instead of 1 updated from arr2.

Comment: Oops, I fixed that now by replacing the `forEach` with a `reduceRight`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(const el of arr2){
 const dupe = arr1.find(e => e.id === el.id);
 if(dupe){
   dupe.quantity = el.quantity;
 }else{
   arr1.push(el);
 }
}
```

But actually a Map (id -> quantity) would be the better datastructure here (or an object):

```
const els = new Map( arr1.map(el => [el.id, el.quantity]));
//to add
arr2.forEach( el => els.set( el.id, el.quantity + (els.get( el.id ) ||0));
```

Comment: In the 2nd solution - add a default `(els.get( el.id ) || 0)` or you'll get a `NaN` if it's not a duplicate.

Comment: nice solution but if the arr2 has lesser elements than arr1 then arr1 doesn't change to arr2.

Comment: @ori yeah i always forget about that... :/